# Unable to set up Certified Programming with Dependent Types

Tags: emacs, coq, proof-general

I am working with the book Certified Programming with Dependent Types but each time I'm finding a different error. It seems to me that the error comes from a mismatch between the compilation process from Proof General and through the makefile of the sources of the book.

1. If I compile the sources with make and try to run for instance Subset.v in Proof-General I get:

> Error: File /home/usuario/Desktop/Coq/cpdt/src/CpdtTactics.vo has
>   bad magic number 81100 (expected 8600). It is corrupted or was
>   compiled with another version of Coq.

2. If I clean the makefile compiled files with make clean and try to proceed with the option Coq -> Auto Compilation -> Compile before require then it is the line:

Require Extraction.

that fails. Originally it failed with the error:

> Error: Unable to locate library Extraction.

but with the above option enables it gives something like:

> echo "Require Extraction." > /tmp/ProofGeneral-coqQPJTf0.v coqdep -Q /home/usuario/Desktop/Coq/cpdt/src/  -R /home/usuario/Desktop/Coq/cpdt/src Cpdt /tmp/ProofGeneral-coqQPJTf0.v
>   *** Warning: in file /tmp/ProofGeneral-coqQPJTf0.v, library Extraction is required and has not been found in the loadpath!
>   *** Warning: in file /tmp/ProofGeneral-coqQPJTf0.v, library Extraction is required and has not been found in the loadpath!
>   /tmp/ProofGeneral-coqQPJTf0.vo /tmp/ProofGeneral-coqQPJTf0.glob /tmp/ProofGeneral-coqQPJTf0.v.beautified: /tmp/ProofGeneral-coqQPJTf0.v
>   /tmp/ProofGeneral-coqQPJTf0.vio: /tmp/ProofGeneral-coqQPJTf0.v

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Side-questions: which OS are you using? do you rely on `opam`?

Regarding the first error you get, it certainly comes from the following fact:

- outside proofgeneral, the `coqc` binary corresponds to Coq 8.11, while in ProofGeneral, the `coqtop` binary correspond to Coq 8.6. Maybe because the `PATH` variable is not the same in the two contexts.
- To figure out which binary is found, you can do in the terminal `which coqtop`, and within Emacs, <kbd>M-! which coqtop RET</kbd> and you should thus get different paths.
- Sometimes, opening `emacs` directly from the terminal (`emacs &`) can help for this kind of issue.
- But if you want to change the `coqtop` binary that is used in ProofGeneral, you can set the `coq-prog-name` option, by using one of the following steps:

  - Interactively, type <kbd>C-u C-c C-x</kbd> (to kill Coq), <kbd>M-: (setq coq-prog-name "…/coqtop")</kbd>, and <kbd>C-c C-n</kbd>
  - Or create a `.dir-locals.el` file (Emacs' standard conf-file) in the project root containing:

    ```
    ((coq-mode . ((coq-prog-name . "…/coqtop"))))
    ```

    and close/reopen the `….v` file at stake (or just do <kbd>M-x normal-mode RET</kbd> or <kbd>C-x C-v RET</kbd> in the already-opened `….v` buffer)

Regarding the second error you get, I'm a bit puzzled that `Require Extraction` triggers this error, as this library does exist in Coq 8.6 and 8.11.

At first sight, I'd suggest to re-test the auto-compilation with Coq 8.11, asserting `From Coq Require Extraction.` (instead of just `Require Extraction.`)

But maybe there is a bug in PG's `Auto Compilation -> Compile before require` feature; anyway feel free to open a related issue in the PG tracker if need be, bug reports and feature requests are very welcome: https://github.com/ProofGeneral/PG/issues